# SQL Server not configured for data access

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, vb6

I'm running a SQL Server 2005 database from a VB 6 Application. I connect to the database 
through an ODBC DSN.

I renamed the computer on which I'm running the default instance of SQL server from 'Software' to 'IT'. I then ran the `sp_dropserver` and `sp_addserver` stored procedures to rename the instance.

On restarting the SQL Server service, the server was able to pick up on the new SQL Server name.

After configuring the ODBC data source name to the new name, the connection was Ok. I'm able to run my application and read records through ADO record sets. However I'm unable to update any recordset using the `.Update` method. I get the following error instead ... `SQL Server not configured for data access`

How can I enable data access on the renamed server instance?

Answer (score 51):

[How to: Rename a Computer that Hosts a Stand-Alone Instance of SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143799(SQL.90).aspx)

You should be able to run this but **not** against any linked server. It's not a linked server. It's local.

```
EXEC sp_serveroption 'YourServer', 'DATA ACCESS', TRUE
```

Comment: Does doing this expose the server to SQL injection or other security issues?

Comment: does not work if your stored procedure uses dynamic sql

Answer (score 5):

Just go to the linked server properties > Server options > Data access --> true

Works on SQL Server 2014.

Regards

Comment: Is "thrue" supposed to be "true" ? Perhaps edit the answer someone?

Answer (score 3):

with this

```sql
use master
go

exec sp_serveroption 'server name', 'data access', 'true'
go
```

linked servers generated for replication still showing same error

Answer (score 3):

I just would like to add to the previous answers that, at least in my case here, I needed to enable data access in both places.

for instance:

there is server A and server B

On server A
I have a linked server LB that links me from server A to server B

I need to execute the following:

-- on server A

```
exec sp_serveroption 'LB', 'data access', 'true'
```

-- on server B

```
exec sp_serveroption 'B', 'data access', 'true'
```

Answer (score 2):

I've just come across this error and found that it was caused by me trying to run OpenQuery against the local server (doh!).  Changing the server name to that of an actual linked server resolved my issue.

Comment: A better fix would be not to use OpenQuery when you don't need to.