# Update sys.servers after renaming SQL Server Host

Tags: sql-server, rename, linked-server

I'm about to upgrade my SQL Server 2012 instance to SQL Server 2014.

I've cloned the host Windows VM and renamed it from `foo-2012` to `foo-2014`.
On restart, SQL Server instance noticed this as updated its own name, so I can now log into it as `foo-2014`. All good.

Unfortunately the (single) entry in `sys.servers` is still `foo-2012` which means that running

```
SELECT * 
FROM [foo-2012].[barDB].[dbo].tFooBarTable
```

fails with:

> Could not find server 'RW-DB-2014' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

Fine.

I run `EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 'foo-2014', 'SQL Server'` and get an entry.

But now the new entry has `isLinked=1` (whereas the existing entry has `isLinked=0`).

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178530.aspx) indicates that this setting is important (especially to my app which has very strong opinions on Distr.Trans. :(  )

I can't edit/add to/modify sys.servers directly. Any attempt to do so gives:

> Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed.

I remove the new entry (`EXEC sp_dropserver 'foo-2014'`) which succeeds, and try using `EXEC sp_addserver 'foo-2014', 'local'` which reports

> The server 'foo-2014' already exists

Immediately re-running the drop then reports

> The server 'RW-DB-2014' does not exist. Use sp_helpserver to show available servers.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I have voted to move this question to DBA.SE

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to first remove the old server `foo-2012` so that you have no rows in `sys.servers`, and then do the add with `'local'`:

```
EXEC sp_dropserver 'foo-2012';
GO
EXEC sp_addserver 'foo-2014', 'local'; 
GO
```

Then you will need to restart the MSSQLSERVER service in order for that change to take effect, as per the documentation for [sp_addserver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174411.aspx#Anchor_1) :

> The local definition takes effect only after the Database Engine is restarted.

Comment: We have a winner :) Note that you also need to actively enable DATA ACCESS after that:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629677/sql-server-not-configured-for-data-access do you want to update your answer to be complete, then I'll accept it.

Comment: Also seemed to need a SQL restart, though that seems unsurprising.

Comment: Sure, will update when I get home. I don't remember the data access part but the reboot makes sense.

Comment: @Brondahl I just updated to include example code and a note about the restart part (that I forgot about, sorry, but it has been 9 years almost since I ran into this ;-). I did not add the part about enabling `DATA ACCESS` since I don't think that is actually required. My local server does not have it enabled, and I would think that `sp_addserver` would set it to enabled if it were necessary. I think it was the reboot that was needed.

Comment: @Brondahl That seems plausible. The comment's there for future users anyway, so they can check it if they want to.